# Is there a way to get @mentions in the messages generated by Azure Devops/Repos/Pipelines when subscribing to service hooks in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams, azure-service-hooks

The reason we want this kind of messaging in a Teams channel is to get rid of some spamming in our mailboxes. Still there is a lot of traffic in this channel and without *mentions* it's easily lost in the chatter.

For example, a message like this is in my opinion useless if I don't notice it:

[image]

I have been using Slack with TeamCity before and had a lot of opportunities for customization.

So my question as stated in the subject is:

Is there a way to get @mentions in the messages generated by Azure Devops/Repos/Pipelines when subscribing to service hooks in Microsoft Teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such feature currently. But I think this is indeed a good suggestion. Here is the [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/563398/ability-for.html) in Developer Community and the current status is on roadmap. Please check if you have the same requirements. You can vote and follow this suggestion ticket.